# a better pattern for authenticated React components and routes

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-router, auth0, redux-saga

I'm working on adding [Auth0](https://auth0.com/docs/libraries/lock) authentication to my React app, and even though I have it working, I feel like there's a better way to approach this. I'm struggling to figure out a better pattern for the authentication logic.

The app setup is [react](https://facebook.github.io/react/) + [redux](https://github.com/reactjs/redux) + [react-router-redux](https://github.com/reactjs/react-router-redux) + [redux-saga](https://github.com/yelouafi/redux-saga) + [immutable](https://github.com/facebook/immutable-js) + [auth0-lock](https://github.com/auth0/lock).

Beginning at the top, the `App` component defines the basic page layout, both `Builder` and `Editor` components require the user to be logged in, and `authenticated()` wraps each in a Higher Order Component responsible for handling authentication.

```
// index.js

import App from './containers/App';
import Builder from './containers/Builder';
import Editor from './containers/Editor';
import Home from './containers/Home';
import Login from './containers/Login';

import AuthContainer from './containers/Auth0/AuthContainer';

...

ReactDOM.render(
  <Provider store={reduxStore}>
    <Router history={syncedHistory}>
      <Route path={'/'} component={App}>
        <IndexRoute component={Home} />
        <Route path={'login'} component={Login} />
        <Route component={AuthContainer}>
          <Route path={'builder'} component={Builder} />
          <Route path={'editor'} component={Editor} />
        </Route>
      </Route>
      <Redirect from={'*'} to={'/'} />
    </Router>
  </Provider>,
  document.getElementById('app')
);
```

At the moment, `AuthContainer` doesn't do much except check the redux store for `isLoggedIn`. If `isLoggedIn` is false, the user is not allowed to view the component, and is redirected to `/login`.

```
// containers/Auth0/AuthContainer.js

import React from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { bindActionCreators } from 'redux';

import { redirectToLogin } from './Auth0Actions';

class AuthContainer extends React.Component {
  componentWillMount() {
    if (!this.props.isLoggedIn) {
      this.props.actions.redirectToLogin();
    }
  }
  render() {
    if (!this.props.isLoggedIn) {
      return null;
    }
    return this.props.children;
  }
}

// mapStateToProps(), mapDispatchToProps()

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(AuthContainer);
```

The next piece is Auth0. The Auth0 Lock works in "redirect" mode, which means the user will leave the app to log in, and then be redirected back to the app at `/login`. As part of the redirect, Auth0 attaches a token as part of the URL, which needs to be parsed when the app loads.

```
const lock = new Auth0Lock(__AUTH0_CLIENT_ID__, __AUTH0_DOMAIN__, {
  auth: {
    redirect: true,
    redirectUrl: `${window.location.origin}/login`,
    responseType: 'token'
  }
});
```

Since Auth0 will redirect to `/login`, the `Login` component also needs authentication logic. Similar to `AuthContainer`, it checks the redux store for `isLoggedIn`. If `isLoggedIn` is true, it redirects to the root `/`. If `isLoggedIn` is false, it'll attempt to authenticate.

```
// containers/Login/index.js

import React from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { bindActionCreators } from 'redux';

import { authenticate, redirectToRoot } from '../Auth0/Auth0Actions';

class Login extends React.Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    if (!this.props.isLoggedIn) {
      this.props.actions.authenticate();
    }
    else {
      this.props.actions.redirectToRoot();
    }
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div>Login Page</div>
    );
  }
}

// mapStateToProps(), mapDispatchToProps()

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(Login);
```

With these pieces in place, my integration with Auth0 seems to be working. However, I now have `AuthContainer` and `Login` component, and they are very similar. I can't place the `Login` component as a child to `AuthContainer` since the login page does not actually require the user to be logged in.

Ideally, all authentication logic lives in one place, but I'm struggling to figure out another way to get it working, especially with the special case of the Auth0 redirect. I can't help but think that there must be a different approach, a better pattern for authentication flow in a react + redux app.

One thing that would be helpful is to better understand how to dispatch an async action on page load, before the app starts initializing. Since Auth0 works with callbacks, I'm forced to delay setting the redux initial state until after Auth0 invokes the registered callback. What is the recommended way to handle async actions on page load?

---

I've left out some pieces for brevity, like the actions and sagas, but I'll be more than happy to provide those if it'll be helpful.

Answer (score 2):

May not be a complete answer, so sorry for that. Few things to address here:

> Ideally, all authentication logic lives in one place

I'm not so sure this is ideal, depending on what you mean by "one place". There's noting wrong with having two functions that are similar but are different enough in some aspect that warrants a little repetition. From what I can see your code the logic is indeed slightly different so two components seems perfectly fine.

**Instead of `componentDidMount`, use Route's `onEnter` prop**

Putting your auth logic after component mounting will likely cause a flicker of your authenticated html showing before the auth logic can run. Conceptually, you would like to prevent rendering this component at all until the auth logic has run. Route's `onEnter` is perfect for this. https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/master/docs/API.md#onenternextstate-replace-callback

```
let authenticate = (nextState, replace) => {
   // check store details here, if not logged in, redirect
}

<Route path={'builder'} onEnter={authenticate} component={Builder} />
```

> how to dispatch an async action on page load, before the app starts initializing

This is quite a common question for React Apps / SPAs. I think the best possible user experience is to display something right away, perhaps a loading spinner or something that says "Fetching user details" or whatnot. You can do this in your top level App container or even before your first call to `ReactDOM.render`

```
ReactDOM.render(<SplashLoader />, element)

authCall().then(data =>
  ReactDOM.render(<App data={data} />, element)
).catch(err =>
  ReactDOM.render(<Login />, element)
}
```

Comment: my first attempt used `onEnter`, but I wasn't able to get it to work (probably just needed more time). also, I was discouraged from using `onEnter` after reading this https://github.com/mjrussell/redux-auth-wrapper#motivation

Comment: I'm not sure what the best practices are or what the best approach is. I do like the idea of using a higher order component for wrapping regular components with a layer dedicated to auth. conceptually, that makes a lot of sense as an abstraction, whereas `onEnter` seems more of a quick fix

Comment: Sure I think that's a fine approach, but in your example your are rendering your component, then doing the auth check after it mounts.. I think maybe instead of a HOC you just have a normal component that displays its children or not after mounting like in @Nguyen's example

Comment: you're right. I shouldn't be using `componentDidMount()`. however, after seeing this thread, https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/7671, I'm not sure if `componentWillMount()` is the right hook either

Comment: It's not about using the wrong hook.. `componentDidMount` is fine.. but you're using that check too low down the tree... the component you're not supposed to show is going to render before componentDidMount fires.. that's why an HOC is the wrong tool for the job.. a regular component that has something like `{this.props.isLoggedIn && this.props.children}` and does the check on `componentDidMount` is better because the inner component will never even call render until you've passed auth

Comment: To make it more clear.. an HOC is something you want to use to add properties and functionality to a component. But you're not doing either of those things, so the HOC is actually complicating things. Regular component is fine

Comment: I see. It seems like you're implying something along the lines of this: https://medium.com/the-many/adding-login-and-authentication-sections-to-your-react-or-react-native-app-7767fd251bd1#.mgomoyqj7. Am I understanding you correctly?

Comment: That seems in line with what I'm saying. Is there a reason that might not work for you?

Comment: I totally understand your point about `AuthComponent` not actually being a true HOC. Thanks for pointing that out. I tried the approach from the post https://medium.com/the-many/adding-login-and-authentication-sections-to-your-react-or-react-native-app-7767fd251bd1#.hozyaz76a, and that works just as well.

Comment: What I'm still stuck on is how to handle the Auth0 redirect back into the app. At the moment, I have to have the `Login` component, which has very similar logic to the `AuthContainer` that wraps the routes.

Answer (score 1):

I'm doing the same thing in my project and working fine with `redux`, `react-router`, just have a look at my code below:

**routes**:

```
export default (
  <div>
  <Route path="/" component={AuthenticatedComponent}>
    <Route path="user" component={User} />
    <Route path="user/:id" component={UserDetail} />
  </Route>    
  <Route path="/" component={notAuthenticatedComponent}>
    <Route path="register" component={RegisterView} />
    <Route path="login" component={LoginView} />
  </Route>    
  </div>
);
```

**AuthenticatedComponent**:

```
    export class AuthenticatedComponent extends React.Component {
      constructor( props ) {
        super( props );   
      }

      componentWillMount() {
        this.props.checkAuth().then( data => {
          if ( data ) {
            this.props.loginUserSuccess( data );
          } else {
            browserHistory.push( '/login' );
          }
        } );
      }

      render() {
        return (
        <div>
          { this.props.isAuthenticated && <div> { this.props.children } </div> }
        </div>
        );
      }
    }
```

**notAuthenticatedComponent**:

```
export class notAuthenticatedComponent extends React.Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props);    
  }

  componentWillMount(){
    this.props.checkAuth().then((data) => {
      if(data && (this.props.location.pathname == 'login')){
        browserHistory.push('/home');
      }
    });
  }

  render(){
    return (
      <div>
      { this.props.children }
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: what's the motivation behind using `componentWillMount()`? I came across this yesterday https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/7671

Answer (score 1):

If you are following the Thanh Nguyen's answer use React's "Constructor" instead of "componentWillMount". As its the recommended way according to the [docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#unsafe_componentwillmount).

Comment: Hi, Welcome to StackOverflow aka. "SO"
Glad to have you apart of the community!
Please be sure to checkout our help section
https://stackoverflow.com/help/